# only one bar after the condition occurs

Tags: pine-script

I would like to mark (ultimately enter the position) if the condition is met (EMA intersection) and the first bar after the condition occurs and after the fulfillment of additional conditions (on the screenshot - above the price level).
If the next EMA intersection occurs - then again we consider only the first bar after the + condition above the price level.
I can't write it with an "if" construct. He always only receives a bar when both conditions are met - that is, when the EMAs cross and if the bar is above the price - and that's not what I mean.
Can someone help me write this?

```
indicator("after_condition")

ema50 = ta.ema(close, 50)
ema200 = ta.ema(close, 200)

poziom =1209

over_level = high > poziom
plotshape(over_level, title='Bar over the level', style=shape.triangledown, size=size.tiny, location=location.top, color=color.new(color.red, 0))


condition = ta.crossover(ema50, ema200) or ta.crossover(ema200,ema50)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HUCLl.png)

I can't write it with an "if" construct.
He always only receives a bar when both conditions are met - that is, when the EMAs cross and if the bar is above the price - and that's not what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use an 'if'.

```
condition = ta.crossover(ema50, ema200) or ta.crossover(ema200,ema50)
```

condition is true ONLY at the close of the bar where the crossover appears.
The bar after, the condition is again False.

Comment: I get it, but how do I program it to mark when this condition occurs? I mean the first occurrence (above the price level) after the previous occurrence of the condition (EMA crossover).